# pulling multiple values from the same tr with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm building a webscape tool to help collect data for a mini sports odd database I'm building. The data I need is located on https://www.actionnetwork.com/mlb/live-odds. The data itself is under the "Bets" section. Below is a sample of the HTML from that page that I'm iterating over and trying to pull the needed data from.

### HTML

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="p-0"></td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-130<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9.5<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-108<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right border-top-1 border-left-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0" style="height:104px">
     <div class="text-center">
        <a class="" href="/subscribe">
           <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="25" height="25" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="" style="stroke:#57A773;stroke-width:2;fill:#FFF">
              <path d="M12,17A2,2 0 0,0 14,15C14,13.89 13.1,13 12,13A2,2 0 0,0 10,15A2,2 0 0,0 12,17M18,8A2,2 0 0,1 20,10V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6A2,2 0 0,1 4,20V10C4,8.89 4.9,8 6,8H7V6A5,5 0 0,1 12,1A5,5 0 0,1 17,6V8H18M12,3A3,3 0 0,0 9,6V8H15V6A3,3 0 0,0 12,3Z"></path>
           </svg>
        </a>
     </div>
  </td>
  <td class="text-right border-left" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block ">51%</span><span class="d-block mt-1 ">49%</span></td>
  <td class="text-right border-right" style="height:104px">
     <a class="" href="/subscribe">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30" height="30" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="" style="stroke:#57A773;stroke-width:2;fill:#FFF">
           <path d="M12,17A2,2 0 0,0 14,15C14,13.89 13.1,13 12,13A2,2 0 0,0 10,15A2,2 0 0,0 12,17M18,8A2,2 0 0,1 20,10V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6A2,2 0 0,1 4,20V10C4,8.89 4.9,8 6,8H7V6A5,5 0 0,1 12,1A5,5 0 0,1 17,6V8H18M12,3A3,3 0 0,0 9,6V8H15V6A3,3 0 0,0 12,3Z"></path>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block ">49%</span><span class="d-block mt-1 ">51%</span></td>
  <td class="text-right border-right" style="height:104px">
     <a class="" href="/subscribe">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30" height="30" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="" style="stroke:#57A773;stroke-width:2;fill:#FFF">
           <path d="M12,17A2,2 0 0,0 14,15C14,13.89 13.1,13 12,13A2,2 0 0,0 10,15A2,2 0 0,0 12,17M18,8A2,2 0 0,1 20,10V20A2,2 0 0,1 18,22H6A2,2 0 0,1 4,20V10C4,8.89 4.9,8 6,8H7V6A5,5 0 0,1 12,1A5,5 0 0,1 17,6V8H18M12,3A3,3 0 0,0 9,6V8H15V6A3,3 0 0,0 12,3Z"></path>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-107<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-107<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-108<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block highlight-green">-109<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span><span class="d-block mt-1 highlight-green">9<span class="fz-1 fz-md-2"></span></span></td>
  <td class="text-right border-left" style="height:104px">No Picks</td>
  <td class="text-right d-flex flex-column" style="height:104px">
     <div><button type="submit" class="btn pointer font-weight-semibold btn-outline-primary m-0 fz-1 text-truncate">+</button></div>
     <div><button type="submit" class="btn pointer font-weight-semibold btn-outline-primary mt-1 fz-1 text-truncate">+</button></div>
  </td>
.............
</tr>
```

Within the actual web page, there's several of these table rows. From each table row I'm trying to pull from the following row:

### Data

```
<td class="text-right border-left" style="height:104px"><span class="d-block ">51%</span><span class="d-block mt-1 ">49%</span></td>
```

**"d-block"** and **"d-block mt-1"** contains the information I need.

Below is the code I'm using to do this:

### Code

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request')

request('https://www.actionnetwork.com/mlb/live-odds', function (err, res, html) 
{
if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);


    $('td.text-right.border-left span.d-block').each(function(i, element) {
        var a = $(this).prev();
        console.log(a.text())
    });

    $('td.text-right.border-left span.d-block').each(function(i, element) {
        var b = $(this).prev();
        console.log(b.text())
    }); 


}
});
```

First, the first cheerio block pulls the data correctly from the website, however, when the second runs and tries to grab the other `<span>` it prints out the results of the first.

The next issue I have is I can't seem to figure out how to log both values I'm scraping at the same time. As it iterates per row, it prints out the first span's set of values, and then moves onto the next and prints out that span's set of values. Ideally, it would print out both values per row as it iterates.

Comment: To be sure, you want: `'51% 49%'` printed?

Comment: Yes. My issue is mainly that I can’t print both together. I’m only able to iterate over one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on one loop, only retrieving the first `span` and then using `.next` to get its sibling.

```
$('td.text-right.border-left span:first-child').each(function(i, element) {
  const a = $(this).text(); // 51%
  const b = $(this).next().text(); // 49%
  console.log(a, b);
});
```